# How to use Cobertura and JUnit reporters with LWC Jest?

Tags: lightning-web-components, unit-test, code-coverage, test-setup, lwc-jest

When creating a new SFDX project, the default Jest configuration for LWC unit tests looks like this:

**jest.config.js**

```
const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');

module.exports = {
  ...jestConfig,
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/.localdevserver']
};
```

By running...

```
sfdx-lwc-jest --coverage
```

...it shows me the current test coverage in the console and generates a lcov coverage report in the `/coverage` directory of my project. However, I need coverage and test results generated with Cobertura and JUnit to be able to properly use them for reporting and publishing in an automated pipeline run. I wonder if it is possible to overwrite or extend this default predefined LWC Jest configuration in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out via the official Jest documentation that you can also overwrite or extend the configuration ([Configuring Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration)).
If you do this as follows, you can also use Cobertura, JUnit or even other reporters:

**Cobertura**

To use Cobertura or other coverage reporters and formats you just need to add the following line to the existing Jest configuration file:

```
coverageReporters: ['clover', 'json', 'text', 'lcov', 'cobertura'],
```

**JUnit**

To have JUnit support enabled you need an additional npm package called `jest-junit` that can be installed as a dev dependency as follows:

```
npm i jest-junit --save-dev
```

To then use this reporter in Jest, it must also be added to the configuration file. The final Jest configuration would then look like this:

```
const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');

module.exports = {
  ...jestConfig,
  coverageReporters: ['clover', 'json', 'text', 'lcov', 'cobertura'],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['/.localdevserver'],
  reporters: [
    'default',
    [
      'jest-junit',
      {
        outputDirectory: 'tests',
        outputName: 'test-results-lwc.xml'
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```